# Посчитать повторяющиеся подряд значения строк без разрывов

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо посчитать какое количество раз подряд повторяются значения в строках.
Есть исходная таблица.

```
| id | action_id |
------------------
| 1  |   100     |
| 2  |   100     |
| 3  |   100     | 
| 4  |   200     |
| 5  |   200     |
| 6  |   300     |
| 7  |   300     |
| 8  |   200     |
| 9  |   100     |
| 10 |   100     |
```

Нужно посчитать, сколько раз подряд повторяется каждое значение action_id. 
Например action_id c id 1-3 повторяется 3 раза, дальше 200 повторяется 2 раза.

```
| id | action_id | повторы подряд
------------------
| 1  |   100     |  3
| 2  |   100     |  3
| 3  |   100     |  3
| 4  |   200     |  2
| 5  |   200     |  2
| 6  |   300     |  2
| 7  |   300     |  2
| 8  |   200     |  1
| 9  |   100     |  2
| 10 |   100     |  2
```

или даже так

```
| action_id | repeats |
|    100    |  3      |
|    200    |  2      |
|    300    |  2      |
|    200    |  1      |
|    100    |  2      |
```

Формат вывода не важен.

Поле id не меняется, не сортируется.

Была идея создать столбец repeats равный нулю и обновить таблицу и увеличивать repeats на единицу от предыдущего, но все равно много вопросов остается (контроль ID чтобы он быль по порядку, c какого id будет считаться первым, с большего или с меньшего ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумалось такое:

```
select t.id,
       t.action_id,
       (select count(1)
          from t t2
         where t2.action_id = t.action_id
           and not exists (select 1
                  from t t3
                 where t3.id between least(t.id, t2.id) and
                       greatest(t.id, t2.id)
                   and t3.action_id <> t2.action_id)) as repeats
  from t
```

Для каждой записи считаем количество записей с совпадающим action_id таких, что между двумя записями нет записей с другим action_id. Должно сработать, но не поручусь что это наиболее эффективный запрос.

Пример на SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/901829/2

**Второй вариант:** С помощью переменных можно отслеживать изменения `action_id` и считать номер группы, по которому затем группировать записи:

```
SET @grp = 0;

SELECT action_id, count(1)
FROM (SELECT 
        @grp:=IF(@action_id = action_id, @grp, @grp+1) AS grp,
        @action_id:=action_id as action_id,
        id
      FROM t
      ORDER BY id) x
GROUP BY action_id, grp
ORDER BY min(id)
```

получится вариант:

```
| action_id | repeats |
|    100    |  3      |
|    200    |  2      |
|    300    |  2      |
|    200    |  1      |
|    100    |  2      |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7c899/29

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! Всё подошло!